# Spring MVC Interceptor with JavaConfig not rendering JSP when returned true from preHandle

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, model-view-controller, interceptor

The interceptor something like:

```
@Component
public class ValidationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        String requesttoken = request.getParameter("token");
        if (requesttoken != null && validate(requesttoken)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect(Error.NOT_FOUND_URL);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And the JavaConfig is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    ValidationInterceptor ValidationInterceptor() {
        return new ValidationInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(ValidationInterceptor());
    }
}
```

When I hit the URL the the view page is not rendered and log says "**This usually means a bug in the framework or a timeout. Response is already committed so there is nothing we can do**"

But when I replace the replace the JavaConfig with XMLConfig as below:

```
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <bean class="ValidationInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

The view is rendered.Can someone help me with this.

Comment: this code is not valid and does not compile. You do not return anything from `preHandle()`i case that the requesttoken is null or invalid.

Comment: Sorry missed out a return statement edited now